# Diferença entre fflush e setbuf

Tags: c, buffer

Qual a diferença entre as funções **`fflush(stdin);`** e **`setbuf(stdin, NULL);**`?

Quando utilizar e quando não utilizar cada uma delas?

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780908/understanding-the-need-of-fflush-and-problems-associated-with-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fflush(stdin)` é usado erroneamente para limpar o buffer de entrada padrão, mas causa *comportamento indefinido* segundo o padrão da linguagem, portanto deve ser evitado a qualquer custo. Particularmente nunca ouvira falar do `setbuf(stdin, NULL)`, mas ao que parece ele desabilita o *buffer* do stdin pelo restante do programa, o que me parece um *overkill* para situações cotidianas.

Se a sua intenção é apenas limpar o buffer da entrada antes ou depois de qualquer operação (como por exemplo, descartar *whitespace* remanescente) existem alternativas mais canônicas e seguras, como por exemplo `scanf(" ")` (descarta whitespace até primeiro caractere imprimível).